# Allow html comments in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Is there a way to preserve html comments in CKEditor? I have ACF disabled (`CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;`) but still can't save html comments.

Comment: IIRC it's just fine. Use `<p>foo <!-- WAT? --> bar</p>` in [demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full) and see that it's preserved. You got to provide us either more info or verify your setup.